# How to calculate $\frac{d}{d y} y'$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Is there a way to evaluate the following expression?

$$ \frac{d}{dy} y' $$

where

$$ y' = \frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Comment: If $\frac{dy}{dx} = a y$, wouldn't $\frac{d}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = a$? (response to a comment that disappeared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Chain Rule,

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy'}{dy} &= \frac{dy'}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}\\
 &= y'' \cdot \frac{1}{y'}\\
&= \frac{y''}{y'}\end{align}$$

Comment: Glad I could help :)